# Trying to read a BLOB as an InputStream but getting Connection Closed error. Spring3 getJdbcTemplate()

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-3

I'm moving an application to use the Spring3 framework and I have code that reads a `BLOB` column from an Oracle Database:

This works:

```
        String fileSqlStr =
                "select file_id, file_content from cpm_file where file_id = 4";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(fileSqlStr);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        int fileId = rs.getInt("file_id");
        InputStream fis = rs.getBinaryStream("file_content");
        ExlBOMImporter ei = new ExlBOMImporter(fis);
```

But when I try writing it with Spring using the `JdbcTemplate` bean:

```
 InputStream is = getJdbcTemplate().query(getFileContentSql, new RowMapper<InputStream>() {

                public InputStream mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    OracleLobHandler lobHandler = new OracleLobHandler();
                    return lobHandler.getBlobAsBinaryStream(rs, "file_content");
                }
            }, fileId).get(0);
 ExlImporter importer = new ExlBOMImporter(is);
 importer.process();
```

I'm getting an `java.io.IOException: Closed Connection` Exception.

I'm thinking that Spring must be closing the connection for the `InputStream` before I get around to process it. Would you guys have a better way of writing this?

**Edit:** Some more depth to the Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Closed Connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream.needBytes(OracleBlobInputStream.java:204)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBufferedStream.readInternal(OracleBufferedStream.java:169)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBufferedStream.read(OracleBufferedStream.java:143)
        at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:92)
        at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:77)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream.needBytes(OracleBlobInputStream.java:204)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Spring will tidy up the connection when it leaves the `query` method.

Easiest solution is to perform your processing inside the `RowMapper`, e.g.

```
getJdbcTemplate().query(getFileContentSql, new RowMapper<Void>() {
    public void mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        OracleLobHandler lobHandler = new OracleLobHandler();
        InputStream inputStream = lobHandler.getBlobAsBinaryStream(rs, "file_content");
        ExlImporter importer = new ExlBOMImporter(inputStream);
        importer.process();
    }
}, fileId);
```

If you only want to handle the first row, then use a `ResultSetExtractor` instead of a `RowMapper`.

Comment: Makes sense. And it works. Thanks for the tip on the ResultSetExtractor Bit.

Answer (score 0):

Another (perhaps simpler) way of preventing Spring from closing your connection prematurely, is by starting a transaction before executing the query.

This can be done in code by inserting

```
session.beginTransaction();
```

Somewhere before executeQuery call.

Comment: I believe it can also be achieved with '@Transactional' annotation, but I did not test this, and it is probably also undesirable to run the entire method in a transaction for the sole purpose of receiving a Blob-result.

Besides, the Transactional annotation only works for public method-calls, so it could also be quite impractical in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

As per `ResultSet::getBinaryStream` documentation, the value can be read in "chunks", that means that if you close the connection and then try to read enough bytes from the stream, it will raise an exception when the next chunk is needed but can not be returned from the database.

As an alternative, you may try reading the whole value by using the `ResultSet::getBytes` method, and then convert it to an InputStream if you need to (instantiating a new `ByteArrayInputStream`).